# Can we remove fixed scroll in carousel slick slider?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm trying to use slick slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. Everything's working perfect, except I can't find an option for free scroll.
I found out that plugins like slick has this option, but I don't want to use another plugins.

How can I remove slidesToScroll to remove fixed scroll?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out there is no any options inside the plugin.